# Show that $\sum _{n=1 } ^{\infty } (n \pi + \pi/2)^{-1 } $ diverges.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Show that $\sum _{n=1 } ^{\infty } (n \pi + \pi/2)^{-1 }  $ diverges.

Both the root test and the ratio test is inconclusive. Can you suggest a series for the series comparison test?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like $\sum 1/n$ to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the *limit comparison test* with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-1}$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{1}{n\pi +\frac{\pi}{2}} \geq \frac{1}{n\pi +n\pi}\geq \frac{1}{8n} =\frac{1}{8}\cdot\frac{1}{n}$$

Answer (score 2):

It is never too pretty to go for the Root and Ratio Tests on the onset. A much more elegant method would be to notice that:

$$  \dfrac{1}{n \pi + \frac{\pi }{2}} = \dfrac{2 }{ 2n \pi  + \pi  } = \dfrac{2}{\pi } \cdot \dfrac{1}{2n + 1} \ge  \dfrac{2}{\pi } \cdot \dfrac{1}{2n + n} =  \dfrac{2}{3 \pi } \cdot \dfrac{1}{n } $$

Now use the fact that the Harmonic Series $ \sum \dfrac 1 n $ diverges.

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle\frac{1}{n\cdot \pi+\frac{\pi}{2}}\ge\frac{1}{n\cdot\pi+\pi} =\frac{1}{\pi}\cdot\frac{1}{n+1}$, and since $\displaystyle\sum\frac{1}{n+1}$ diverges thus $$\sum\displaystyle\frac{1}{n\cdot \pi+\frac{\pi}{2}}$$ diverges!